# Erro na conexão SQL Server depois de atualizar DBeaver Community

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, java-8, dbeaver

Coloco todos os dados da minha conexão porém está dando este erro:

```
com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver 
 has been compiled by a more recent version of the 
 Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version
 of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

Isso começou logo após atualizar o DBeaver Community para a versão 23.0, já tentei atualizar o Java Runtime, mas não adiantou

[image: O erro é esse como está na imagem]

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar a mensagem de erro dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O roteiro abaixo foi feito com base no Sistema Operacional Windows 11. Creio que, com os devidos ajustes, poderá ser aplicado para os demais Sistemas Operacionais também.

1. Baixar a versão mais recente do Java SE. No caso, no tempo desse post, usei 19.0.2 (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-windows)
2. Localizar a pasta onde está instalada a versão mais recente do Java SE (Exemplo: C:\Program Files\Java).
3. Copiar a pasta da instalação do Java SE (Exemplo: jdk-19) para dentro da instalação do Dbeaver (C:\Program Files\DBeaver).
4. Se houver alguma pasta com nome jre dentro da Instalação do Dbeaver renomeá-la ou apagá-la. Obs: como já não está funcionando mesmo, apagar não afetaria em nada
5. Renomear a pasta que foi copiada no passo 3 para jre
6. Abrir o Dbeaver e testar se a conexão com o SQL Server agora está funcionando.

Comment: a dica ajudou aqui, só que eu baixei a versão compactada(x64 Compressed Archive) do JDK, https://download.oracle.com/java/19/latest/jdk-19_windows-x64_bin.zip e extrai na pasta dbeaver e renomeei pra jre, substituindo a JRE atual da pasta. obrigado